# Fixing a fatal error with PECL/PEAR with multiple php versions

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, pear, pecl

I need to install a PHP package using PECL on a server. However, I keep getting the following error while executing any `pecl` or `pear` command.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Config.php on line 2095
```

The server is running on Ubuntu 18.04. There is multiple PHP versions installed PHP 7.3, PHP 7.4, and PHP 8.O. The default console PHP version is 8.0. The PEAR version 1:1.10.8.

First, I tried to confirm that the correct PHP version is being used in PECL by: `pecl config-set php_suffix=8.0` and trying to view the PECL configuration: `pecl show-config`. These gave the same error since it uses the Config.php file.

So, I found that there was PHP 8.0 incompatibility with the version of PEAR that is installed. So, I attempted to update the PEAR version to 1.10.12 since there an update that was pending for this version.

However, I ran `sudo apt-get install php-pear` which gave a dpkg error. So, I executed: `sudo dpkg --configure -a` which fixed the error. However, then I received the error that broken packages error for linux packages so I executed: `apt --fix-broken install`.

But now, the updated version of PEAR 1.10.12 was no longer available to install using apt. I have tried:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install php-pear
```

But now I get that php-pear is installed to the latest version: 1.10.8.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has reached end of life (outside of paid support plans), and if you were relying on [Ondřej Surý's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) for version support, [the packages for that version of Ubuntu are no longer available](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1922). This may be why you can no longer see any newer versions of PEAR.